# Getting tkinter.Entry input into if/else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my current code, which I have changed multiple times using different answers of different answered questions on here. The problem is I am trying to find a way to get the code to output different answers according to the user input through the tkinter.Entry().

For example, if the user inputs "screen" then the code will give out something about screens. If user inputs "Python" then the code will print something to do with python programming language.

I am able to get the code to print what the user inputed on button click through the .get() function, however this way it will not communicate with the if/else statements.

---

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Try code")

entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

def on_button():
    if entry.get() == "Screen""screen":
        slabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="Screen was entered")
        slabel.pack()
    else:
        tlabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="")
        tlabel.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Enter", command=on_button)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if entry.get() == "Screen""screen":` is only true if the entry text is exactly equal to `Screenscreen`.

Comment: `if entry.get().strip().lower() == "screen":`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert string to lower case and compare only with `"screen"`

```
 if entry.get().strip().lower() == "screen":
```

I use `strip()` to remove spaces at the both ends of string because sometimes user can enter extra spaces ie. `"  screen "`

Or you can use `in`

```
 if entry.get().strip() in ("Screen", "screen", "Monitor", "monitor"):

 if entry.get().strip().lower() in ("screen", "monitor"):
```

because it is shorter then

```
 if entry.get().strip() == "Screen" or entry.get().strip() == "screen" or entry.get().strip() == "Monitor" or entry.get().strip() == "monitor":

 if entry.get().strip().lower() == "screen" or entry.get().strip().lower() == "monitor":
```

You can also use `strip().lower()` before `if/else`

```
 answer = entry.get().strip().lower()

 if answer in ("screen", "monitor"):
     # ...
 elif answer in ("mouse", "trackball"):
     # ...
 elif answer == "keyboard":
     # ...
```

Working example

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---
# `bind` sends `event` to function so it has to receive it
# `command=` doesn't sends `event` so it need some default value - ie. None
def on_button(event=None): 

    answer = entry.get().strip().lower()

    if answer in ("screen", "monitor"):
        # change text in existing label
        label['text'] = "Your {} is dirty. I can't see you.".format(answer)

    elif answer in ("mouse", "trackball"):
        label['text'] = "Your {} is too slow for me".format(answer)

    else:
        label['text'] = "{0}? What is {0}?".format(answer)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Try code")

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

# run function when in `entry` you press `ENTER` on keyboard 
entry.bind('<Return>', on_button) 

button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=on_button)
button.pack()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

# activate `entry` so you don't have to click in `entry` to start typing
entry.focus() 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I decided to use the simple if entry.get().strip().lower() in ("screen", "monitor"): method...however is there a way to make it work for phrases such as "cracked screen" which would be different to "unresponsive screen"

Answer (score 1):

Your Boolean expression in your if statement was not right.You have to explicitly tell Python what exactly you want to do:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Try code")

entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
print(entry.get())
def on_button():
    if entry.get() == "Screen" or entry.get() == "screen": #corrected
        slabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="Screen was entered")
        slabel.pack()
    else:
        tlabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="")
        tlabel.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Enter", command=on_button)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And now it works:

[image]