# Is there a way to make an OptionMenu() unavailable before there is an int in an Entry()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, optionmenu

I'm making a GUI for my code and I need to get some user input. I have an Entry() and an OptionMenu() and I want the OptionMenu() to be in range(1, number inputted in Entry() + 1).

I create the Entry() and then I set up the OptionMenu() with the list being the range from 1 to the number entered into e1.

The program doesn't want to start, because e1 is = to '' and that can't be inputted into a range.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *  

root = Tk()  

e1 = Entry(root)  

var = StringVar(root)  
var.set(3)  

ls = list(range(1, int(e1.get()) + 1))  

o1 = OptionMenu(root, var, *ls)  

root.mainloop()
```

What should I do about this? Is there a way to make the OptionMenu() unavailable until there is an int in the Entry() using if and try: + except: ValueError ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41086016/1531971 You need to test your value prior to using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a button that when the user presses it updates the `OptionMenu()`, or you could maybe have a thread that is created on startup that scans the `Entry` field every so often and updates the list box accordingly. The thread would have the advantage of being hidden from the user, but the disadvantage of additional computational work. I would likely implement one of those two options, but I'm sure that there are more possibilities!

Per request I'll elaborate on how I would approach this problem via my button method described above

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk # for the Combobox widget


class OOP:
    def __init__(self): # initialize our GUI
        self.win = tk.Tk() # initialize main window
        self.user_selected_option = tk.StringVar() # make a variable that can .get() what the user selects from the menu
        self.user_entry = tk.IntVar()
        self.user_entry.set(3) # set the initial number or options to be 1-3
        possible_range = [i for i in range(1, self.user_entry.get() + 1)]
        tk.Entry(self.win, textvariable=self.user_entry).pack(fill='both')
        self.option_menu = ttk.Combobox(self.win, state='readonly', textvariable=self.user_selected_option, values=tuple(possible_range))
        self.option_menu.pack(fill='both') # we pack it into the GUI
        tk.Button(self.win, text='Update', command=self.update_option_menu).pack(fill='both') # we make a button that updates the options available

    def update_option_menu(self): # we make a function to update the buttons that the button command is linked to
        possible_range = [i for i in range(1, self.user_entry.get() + 1)] # we create a list of values to display (same code as above)
        self.option_menu.configure(values=possible_range) # we update the values in the Combobox via its .configure() method


app = OOP() # with the class now defined we make an instance of it
app.win.mainloop() # And we spin up a GUI for that instance
```

I used OOP (object oriented programming) because I believe it can achieve more with less code, as well as create more reusable code for the future. It also solves your problem of *needing to be initialized* by having an **init** method standard for all Python classes. Hopefully my comments sufficiently explain this, but I'll edit it if clarification is needed

Comment: So if I do something like this:

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e1 = Entry(root)

var = StringVar(root)
var.set(3)

if e1 == 0:
    ls = list(range(1, 6))
elif e1 != 0:
    try:
        ls = list(range(1, int(e1.get())))
    except ValueError:
        ls = list(range(1, 6))

o1 = OptionMenu(root, var, *ls)

e1.pack()
o1.pack()

root.mainloop()

How do I make the list update ? Because now the app starts up, but the list isn't updated. Thanx

Comment: Thank you very much for yout help !